# Why can't Makefile find include directories

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I can't seem to include a header in my test program using a Makefile.

I've attempted to try relative paths using `-I` with no luck. I'm new to Make and for some reason I am having a hard time understanding it's usage.

my code, `test.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <results/enumTest.h>

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

and my Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu++11 -m64 -Iinclude

test: test.o
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -I/.. -o  test test.o 

test.o: test.cpp
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -I/.. -c test.cpp
```

my directory structure:

```
/testDir/
  ./results/enuMtest.h
  ./test/test.cpp
  ./test/Makefile
```

I would hope that I could compile and then run the test software using a Makefile. This is more or less a tutorial for me.

Comment: Do you still see the problem if you change the include to `#include "results/enumTest.h"`?  It appears you have C++ source files, but you are using `gcc` for them.  That may be bad.

Comment: How to you invoke `make` and from which directory?

Comment: As an aside, `-I/..` actually refers to the non-existent parent of the root directory.  I think you probably meant `-I../` instead.

Comment: `-I/..` is kind of strange... Did you try with `-I..` ?

Comment: That was indeed my problem. Both answers given below were very helpful. I accepted the one that I did because it did a better job of describing the specified issue regarding includes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your include path `-I/..` is invalid. You're trying to access the parent directory of the root directory, which cannot exist. Change your Makefile to use relative paths instead with `-I..`

This will access the parent directory as intended:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu++11 -m64 -Iinclude

test: test.o
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -I.. -o  test test.o # Change here

test.o: test.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -I.. -c test.cpp # ...and here
```

Note the removed slashes.

EDIT: As commented by @Lightness, you should include non-system headers with `"header.h"` rather than `<header.h>`. Additionally, since you are trying to compile a C++ program, it is recommended to use `g++` instead of `gcc` (I've updated this in the snippet above).

Answer (score 5):

There are several improvements possible.

- You try to set the include path to the parent dir of / which is /.
- You try to compile a c++ program using gcc but not g++
- You don't need (it would still work) to set an include path, when linking. (test:
  test.o)
- Since there is no directory named include in the filetree you specified, you also don't need -Iinclude in the CFLAGS
- Usually the C++ variant of CFLAGS is named CXXFLAGS, but I did not change it in the modified example below.

A corrected makefile would be:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu++11 -m64

test: test.o
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o  test test.o 

test.o: test.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -I.. -c test.cpp
```

As an additional note:

`#include ""` instead of `#include <>` would also work. The difference is, that `""` searches the included file relative from the location of the current source file, while `<>` uses the directories you specify using `-I`.
Find more details [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html)